# Android 8 App crashing on super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) In Theme.AppCompat.Dialog

Tags: android

java.lang.RuntimeException:

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3194)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3302)

at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (Unknown Source)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1891)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:1081)

at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.onCreate (SupportActivity.java:66)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:321)

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:84)

> ```
> at super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> ```

at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7372)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1218)

Comment: some context would be helpful

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), glad to see a new member! Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and make your question a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); crashing in this line what should i do please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue. I suspect that, if you are using a fragment in this activity, perhaps that fragment is going missing somehow?